# Disable column from header filtering but leave in toolbar

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, toolbar

I got next jqGrid table.

[image: jqgrid]

I want to disable filter ability from header column, but leave it in filter toolbar.

Is there any way to disable `ui-search-input` but leave it in total column list? In this case for **Notes** column for example.

How to do it in the most convenient way?

**UPD**
I need to remove field marked with red arrow and leave green arrow field

```js
$(function () {
        var grid_selector = "#grid-table",
            pager_selector = "#grid-pager",
            $jqGridReport = $(grid_selector),
            grid_data =
                [
                    {id: "1", name: "Desktop Computer", note: "note", stock: "Yes", ship: "FedEx", sdate: "2007-12-03"},
                    {id: "2", name: "Laptop", note: "Long text ", stock: "Yes", ship: "InTime", sdate: "2007-12-03"},
                    {id: "3", name: "LCD Monitor", note: "note3", stock: "Yes", ship: "TNT", sdate: "2007-12-03"},
                    {id: "4", name: "Speakers", note: "note", stock: "No", ship: "ARAMEX", sdate: "2007-12-03"},
                    {id: "5", name: "Laser Printer", note: "note2", stock: "Yes", ship: "FedEx", sdate: "2007-12-03"},
                    {id: "6", name: "Play Station", note: "note3", stock: "No", ship: "FedEx", sdate: "2007-12-03"},
                    {
                        id: "7",
                        name: "Mobile Telephone",
                        note: "note",
                        stock: "Yes",
                        ship: "ARAMEX",
                        sdate: "2007-12-03"
                    },
                    {id: "8", name: "Server", note: "note2", stock: "Yes", ship: "TNT", sdate: "2007-12-03"},
                    {id: "9", name: "Matrix Printer", note: "note3", stock: "No", ship: "FedEx", sdate: "2007-12-03"},
                    {
                        id: "10",
                        name: "Desktop Computer",
                        note: "note",
                        stock: "Yes",
                        ship: "FedEx",
                        sdate: "2007-12-03"
                    },
                    {id: "11", name: "Laptop", note: "Long text ", stock: "Yes", ship: "InTime", sdate: "2007-12-03"},
                    {id: "12", name: "LCD Monitor", note: "note3", stock: "Yes", ship: "TNT", sdate: "2007-12-03"},
                    {id: "13", name: "Speakers", note: "note", stock: "No", ship: "ARAMEX", sdate: "2007-12-03"},
                    {id: "14", name: "Laser Printer", note: "note2", stock: "Yes", ship: "FedEx", sdate: "2007-12-03"},
                    {id: "15", name: "Play Station", note: "note3", stock: "No", ship: "FedEx", sdate: "2007-12-03"},
                    {
                        id: "16",
                        name: "Mobile Telephone",
                        note: "note",
                        stock: "Yes",
                        ship: "ARAMEX",
                        sdate: "2007-12-03"
                    },
                    {id: "17", name: "Server", note: "note2", stock: "Yes", ship: "TNT", sdate: "2007-12-03"},
                    {id: "18", name: "Matrix Printer", note: "note3", stock: "No", ship: "FedEx", sdate: "2007-12-03"},
                    {id: "19", name: "Matrix Printer", note: "note3", stock: "No", ship: "FedEx", sdate: "2007-12-03"},
                    {
                        id: "20",
                        name: "Desktop Computer",
                        note: "note",
                        stock: "Yes",
                        ship: "FedEx",
                        sdate: "2007-12-03"
                    },
                    {id: "21", name: "Laptop", note: "Long text ", stock: "Yes", ship: "InTime", sdate: "2007-12-03"},
                    {id: "22", name: "LCD Monitor", note: "note3", stock: "Yes", ship: "TNT", sdate: "2007-12-03"},
                    {id: "23", name: "Speakers", note: "note", stock: "No", ship: "ARAMEX", sdate: "2007-12-03"}
                ];


        //resize to fit page size
        $(window).on('resize.jqGrid', function () {
            $(grid_selector).jqGrid('setGridWidth', $(".page-content").width());
        })
        //resize on sidebar collapse/expand
        var parent_column = $(grid_selector).closest('[class*="col-"]');
        $(document).on('settings.ace.jqGrid', function (ev, event_name, collapsed) {
            if (event_name === 'sidebar_collapsed' || event_name === 'main_container_fixed') {
                //setTimeout is for webkit only to give time for DOM changes and then redraw!!!
                setTimeout(function () {
                    $(grid_selector).jqGrid('setGridWidth', parent_column.width());
                }, 0);
            }
        })

        $jqGridReport.jqGrid({
            subGrid: false,

            data: grid_data,
            datatype: "local",
            height: 'auto',
            colNames: ['ID', 'Name', 'Ship via', 'Notes'],
            colModel: [
                {name: 'id', index: 'id', width: 60, search: true, sorttype: "int", editable: true},
                {name: 'name', index: 'name', width: 150, editable: true, editoptions: {size: "20", maxlength: "30"}},
                {
                    name: 'ship',
                    index: 'ship',
                    width: 90,
                    editable: true,
                    edittype: "select",
                    editoptions: {value: "FE:FedEx;IN:InTime;TN:TNT;AR:ARAMEX"}
                },
                {
                    name: 'note',
                    index: 'note',
                    width: 150,
                    sortable: false,
                    editable: true,
                    edittype: "textarea",
                    editoptions: {rows: "2", cols: "10"}
                }
            ],

            viewrecords: true,
            rowNum: 10,
            rowList: [10, 25, 50, 100],
            pager: pager_selector,
            altRows: true,

            multiselect: false,
            multiboxonly: true,

            editurl: "/dummy.html",//nothing is saved
            caption: "jgGrid Example"
        });

        $(grid_selector).jqGrid('navGrid', pager_selector,
            {  //navbar options
                edit: false,
                editicon: 'ace-icon fa fa-pencil blue',
                add: false,
                addicon: 'ace-icon fa fa-plus-circle purple',
                del: false,
                delicon: 'ace-icon fa fa-trash-o red',
                search: true,
                searchicon: 'ace-icon fa fa-search green',
                refresh: false,
                refreshicon: 'ace-icon fa fa-refresh green',
                view: false,
                viewicon: 'ace-icon fa fa-search-plus grey',
            },
            {},
            {},
            {},
            {
                //search form
                recreateForm: true,
                afterShowSearch: function (e) {
                    var form = $(e[0]);
                    form.closest('.ui-jqdialog').find('.ui-jqdialog-title').wrap('<div class="widget-header" />')
                    style_search_form(form);
                },
                afterRedraw: function () {
                    style_search_filters($(this));
                }
                ,
                multipleSearch: true,
                /**
                 multipleGroup:true,
                 showQuery: true
                 */
            },
            {}
        );

        function style_search_filters(form) {
            form.find('.delete-rule').val('X');
            form.find('.add-rule').addClass('btn btn-xs btn-primary');
            form.find('.add-group').addClass('btn btn-xs btn-success');
            form.find('.delete-group').addClass('btn btn-xs btn-danger');
        }

        function style_search_form(form) {
            var dialog = form.closest('.ui-jqdialog');
            var buttons = dialog.find('.EditTable')
            buttons.find('.EditButton a[id*="_reset"]').addClass('btn btn-sm btn-info').find('.ui-icon').attr('class', 'ace-icon fa fa-retweet');
            buttons.find('.EditButton a[id*="_query"]').addClass('btn btn-sm btn-inverse').find('.ui-icon').attr('class', 'ace-icon fa fa-comment-o');
            buttons.find('.EditButton a[id*="_search"]').addClass('btn btn-sm btn-purple').find('.ui-icon').attr('class', 'ace-icon fa fa-search');
        }

        $jqGridReport.jqGrid('filterToolbar', {autosearch: true, stringResult: false});
    });
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqgrid/4.6.0/js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqgrid/4.6.0/js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqgrid/4.6.0/css/ui.jqgrid.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqgrid/4.6.0/plugins/searchFilter.css">
<table id="grid-table"></table>
<div id="grid-pager"></div>
```

### Expected result

```js
$(function () {
        var grid_selector = "#grid-table",
            pager_selector = "#grid-pager",
            $jqGridReport = $(grid_selector),
            grid_data =
                [
                    {id: "1", name: "Desktop Computer", note: "note", stock: "Yes", ship: "FedEx", sdate: "2007-12-03"},
                    {id: "2", name: "Laptop", note: "Long text ", stock: "Yes", ship: "InTime", sdate: "2007-12-03"},
                    {id: "3", name: "LCD Monitor", note: "note3", stock: "Yes", ship: "TNT", sdate: "2007-12-03"},
                    {id: "4", name: "Speakers", note: "note", stock: "No", ship: "ARAMEX", sdate: "2007-12-03"},
                    {id: "5", name: "Laser Printer", note: "note2", stock: "Yes", ship: "FedEx", sdate: "2007-12-03"},
                    {id: "6", name: "Play Station", note: "note3", stock: "No", ship: "FedEx", sdate: "2007-12-03"},
                    {
                        id: "7",
                        name: "Mobile Telephone",
                        note: "note",
                        stock: "Yes",
                        ship: "ARAMEX",
                        sdate: "2007-12-03"
                    },
                    {id: "8", name: "Server", note: "note2", stock: "Yes", ship: "TNT", sdate: "2007-12-03"},
                    {id: "9", name: "Matrix Printer", note: "note3", stock: "No", ship: "FedEx", sdate: "2007-12-03"},
                    {
                        id: "10",
                        name: "Desktop Computer",
                        note: "note",
                        stock: "Yes",
                        ship: "FedEx",
                        sdate: "2007-12-03"
                    },
                    {id: "11", name: "Laptop", note: "Long text ", stock: "Yes", ship: "InTime", sdate: "2007-12-03"},
                    {id: "12", name: "LCD Monitor", note: "note3", stock: "Yes", ship: "TNT", sdate: "2007-12-03"},
                    {id: "13", name: "Speakers", note: "note", stock: "No", ship: "ARAMEX", sdate: "2007-12-03"},
                    {id: "14", name: "Laser Printer", note: "note2", stock: "Yes", ship: "FedEx", sdate: "2007-12-03"},
                    {id: "15", name: "Play Station", note: "note3", stock: "No", ship: "FedEx", sdate: "2007-12-03"},
                    {
                        id: "16",
                        name: "Mobile Telephone",
                        note: "note",
                        stock: "Yes",
                        ship: "ARAMEX",
                        sdate: "2007-12-03"
                    },
                    {id: "17", name: "Server", note: "note2", stock: "Yes", ship: "TNT", sdate: "2007-12-03"},
                    {id: "18", name: "Matrix Printer", note: "note3", stock: "No", ship: "FedEx", sdate: "2007-12-03"},
                    {id: "19", name: "Matrix Printer", note: "note3", stock: "No", ship: "FedEx", sdate: "2007-12-03"},
                    {
                        id: "20",
                        name: "Desktop Computer",
                        note: "note",
                        stock: "Yes",
                        ship: "FedEx",
                        sdate: "2007-12-03"
                    },
                    {id: "21", name: "Laptop", note: "Long text ", stock: "Yes", ship: "InTime", sdate: "2007-12-03"},
                    {id: "22", name: "LCD Monitor", note: "note3", stock: "Yes", ship: "TNT", sdate: "2007-12-03"},
                    {id: "23", name: "Speakers", note: "note", stock: "No", ship: "ARAMEX", sdate: "2007-12-03"}
                ];


        //resize to fit page size
        $(window).on('resize.jqGrid', function () {
            $(grid_selector).jqGrid('setGridWidth', $(".page-content").width());
        })
        //resize on sidebar collapse/expand
        var parent_column = $(grid_selector).closest('[class*="col-"]');
        $(document).on('settings.ace.jqGrid', function (ev, event_name, collapsed) {
            if (event_name === 'sidebar_collapsed' || event_name === 'main_container_fixed') {
                //setTimeout is for webkit only to give time for DOM changes and then redraw!!!
                setTimeout(function () {
                    $(grid_selector).jqGrid('setGridWidth', parent_column.width());
                }, 0);
            }
        })

        $jqGridReport.jqGrid({
            subGrid: false,

            data: grid_data,
            datatype: "local",
            height: 'auto',
            colNames: ['ID', 'Name', 'Ship via', 'Notes'],
            colModel: [
                {name: 'id', index: 'id', width: 60, search: true, sorttype: "int", editable: true},
                {name: 'name', index: 'name', width: 150, editable: true, editoptions: {size: "20", maxlength: "30"}},
                {
                    name: 'ship',
                    index: 'ship',
                    width: 90,
                    editable: true,
                    edittype: "select",
                    editoptions: {value: "FE:FedEx;IN:InTime;TN:TNT;AR:ARAMEX"}
                },
                {
                    name: 'note',
                    index: 'note',
                    width: 150,
                    search: false,
                    sortable: false,
                    editable: true,
                    edittype: "textarea",
                    editoptions: {rows: "2", cols: "10"}
                }
            ],

            viewrecords: true,
            rowNum: 10,
            rowList: [10, 25, 50, 100],
            pager: pager_selector,
            altRows: true,

            multiselect: false,
            multiboxonly: true,

            editurl: "/dummy.html",//nothing is saved
            caption: "jgGrid Example"
        });

        $(grid_selector).jqGrid('navGrid', pager_selector,
            {  //navbar options
                edit: false,
                editicon: 'ace-icon fa fa-pencil blue',
                add: false,
                addicon: 'ace-icon fa fa-plus-circle purple',
                del: false,
                delicon: 'ace-icon fa fa-trash-o red',
                search: true,
                searchicon: 'ace-icon fa fa-search green',
                refresh: false,
                refreshicon: 'ace-icon fa fa-refresh green',
                view: false,
                viewicon: 'ace-icon fa fa-search-plus grey',
            },
            {},
            {},
            {},
            {
                //search form
                recreateForm: true,
                afterShowSearch: function (e) {
                    var form = $(e[0]);
                    form.closest('.ui-jqdialog').find('.ui-jqdialog-title').wrap('<div class="widget-header" />')
                    style_search_form(form);
                },
                afterRedraw: function () {
                    style_search_filters($(this));
                }
                ,
                multipleSearch: true,
                columns: [{name: "id", sorttype: "int"}, {name: "name"}, {name: "ship"}, {name: "note"}]
                /**
                 multipleGroup:true,
                 showQuery: true
                 */
            },
            {}
        );

        function style_search_filters(form) {
            form.find('.delete-rule').val('X');
            form.find('.add-rule').addClass('btn btn-xs btn-primary');
            form.find('.add-group').addClass('btn btn-xs btn-success');
            form.find('.delete-group').addClass('btn btn-xs btn-danger');
        }

        function style_search_form(form) {
            var dialog = form.closest('.ui-jqdialog');
            var buttons = dialog.find('.EditTable')
            buttons.find('.EditButton a[id*="_reset"]').addClass('btn btn-sm btn-info').find('.ui-icon').attr('class', 'ace-icon fa fa-retweet');
            buttons.find('.EditButton a[id*="_query"]').addClass('btn btn-sm btn-inverse').find('.ui-icon').attr('class', 'ace-icon fa fa-comment-o');
            buttons.find('.EditButton a[id*="_search"]').addClass('btn btn-sm btn-purple').find('.ui-icon').attr('class', 'ace-icon fa fa-search');
        }

        $jqGridReport.jqGrid('filterToolbar', {autosearch: true, stringResult: false});
    });
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqgrid/4.6.0/js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqgrid/4.6.0/js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqgrid/4.6.0/css/ui.jqgrid.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqgrid/4.6.0/plugins/searchFilter.css">
<table id="grid-table"></table>
<div id="grid-pager"></div>
```

Comment: Which **version** of jqGrid you use (can use) and from which **fork** of jqGrid ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid version <=4.7)? You use Bootstrap CSS only in your demo without jQuery UI CSS, but you include old jqGrid 4.6, which not support Bootstrap and which require jQuery UI CSS. You wrote "I want to disable filter ability from header column, but leave it in filter toolbar". What you mean under filter in header column? I suppose that you want to customize the Advance Searching Dialog.

Comment: If I correctly understand, what you need, then you can solve your problem by usage of `columns` option of searching dialog (near `multipleSearch: true` option), but the exact solution depends on the version/fork of jqGrid, which you use. Try `columns: [{name: "id", sorttype: "int"}, {name: "name"}, {name: "ship"}]` for example

Comment: @Oleg I use 4.6.0 version of jqFrid

Comment: @Oleg about _under filter in header column_ I mean remove field marked with red arrow on screen, but leave field with green arrow

Comment: @Oleg in this case I can solve my problem by setup `{ name: 'note', index: 'note', width: 150, search: false }` and put all columns list into navGrid object `columns: [{name: "id", sorttype: "int"}, {name: "name"}, {name: "ship"}, {name: "note"}]`.

But in real project I form colModel dynamically. Is there any way to add setup column to show only in filter toolbar by colModel?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand which problem you have with dynamic `colModel`. You should have some information, which columns you want to have not searchable in the filter toolbar, but to have in searching dialog. You need to set `search: false` for the column(s). You need just build `columns` option **dynamically** too: build `columns` using all searchable columns and add columns which you additionally allow to search in searching dialog.

Comment: @Oleg really I do now that you proposed in last comment. I not such familiar with jqGrid and just want to ask is it possible to do through `colModel`. If it isn't implemented, your variant is great solution. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I correctly understand the problem, then you can do the following:

1. add `search: false` to the column `note`, which you want not have in the filter toolbar.
2. add `columns` option to searching options of `navGrid`. For example, you can use `columns: [{name: "id", sorttype: "int"}, {name: "name"}, {name: "ship"}, {name: "note"}]`

Clarifying the above steps: searching dialog use by default *the same* columns like the filter toolbar. The property `search: false` in the column `note` force removing searching functionality for the column `note`. Adding `columns` option allows to include some columns independent on the value of `search` property. Additionally you specify the order of columns displayed in searching dialog.

Comment: Is it possibly to do it by colModel?

Comment: @PavloZhukov: No, it's not possible. `colModel` have **one** property `search`, which is *common* for searching dialog and the filter toolbar. `filterToolbar` include all columns, which has no `search: false` property. One have no other possibilities. Searching dialog include *the same* columns (which don't has `search: false`), but you have possibility to use `columns` option to build alternative list of columns. It's what I suggest you to do.

Comment: @PavloZhukov: I'd recommend you additionally to consider migrating from very old version 4.6 (3.5 years old) to [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) 4.15.1, which I develop. It supports Bootsrap and Font Awesome without any tricks. See [here](https://free-jqgrid.github.io/getting-started/index.html#bootstrap) an example

Comment: Do I correctly understand that I need to manually form columns with `search: true` and my custom filter columns? There is no other way to just merge columns with `search:true` and my custom filter columns in navGrid search config object?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't migrate to new version because it used in many places project is old and mostly I work on this myself and customer doesn't want to upgrade used technology

Comment: @PavloZhukov: Look at [the line](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/v4.6.0/js/grid.formedit.js#L101) and [the lines](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/v4.6.0/js/grid.formedit.js#L108-L129) of code jqGrid 4.6. It shows how it fills `columns` if no `columns` option is specified. After that jqGrid calls `jqFilter`, which displays the dialog (see [here](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/v4.6.0/js/grid.formedit.js#L154-L177)). There are no other callbacks, which would allow to merge columns. Manual filling of `columns` is very easy. You can just use `colModel` elements.

Comment: @PavloZhukov: I waned to stress that there are no way to "merge" some information to `columns`, which jqGrid build by default. You have to use default way of building `columns` or to build `columns` yourself.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for your investigation. Now I just merge colModels with predefined columns `filterColumns.push({name: columnConfig.name, sopt: sopt});` But I get some trouble. What parameter I need to send to get titles defined in `colNames`?

Comment: @PavloZhukov: I don't understand what you do exactly. It's better if you prepare jsfiddle demo and I would modify it to make it working.

Comment: I found it. That `label` property in `columns:[{label:''}]`

Comment: @PavloZhukov: I'm not sure what problem you had, but `label` property can be used to specify *alternative names* of columns used in editing and searching dialogs. I don't think that `columns:[{label:''}]` option would be good. I repeat that you should provide more full demo which demonstrates which problems you still have.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion there is other solution (if I understand correct)
The idea is the calling order of the methods filterToolbar and navGrid.

Initially in colModel the fields that should not appear in filterTollber should be set with search false

```
$jqGridReport..qGrid({
...
colModel [ 
    ...
    {name : 'note', ..., search : false...}
...
],
...
```

The second step is to call first filter toolbar

```
$jqGridReport.jqGrid('filterToolbar', {autosearch: true, stringResult: false});
```

use setColProp to change the serch to true

```
$jqGridReport.jqGrid('setColProp', 'note', {search : true});
```

and then call navGrid

```
$jqGridReport.jqGrid('navGrid', ...);
```

This way note will not be present in header search, but available in dialog search